ERROR: Could not build wheels for language-check, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
I am trying to install pycontractions via command prompt.
pip install pycontractions
However, it seems to require language-check installation beforehand. I had tried to install language-check but it also showed the same error.
I would appreciate any help given.
enter image description here

please include the full error as text! (though including the image can still be helpful) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question .. does this happen if you try again?
